# Merge rows and convert a string in row value to a user-defined one when condition related to other columns is matched

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Assuming I'm dealing with this dataframe:

| ID | Qualified | Year | Amount A | Amount B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | 2020 | 0 | 150 |
| 1 | No | 2019 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | Yes | 2019 | 10 | 15 |
| 1 | No | 2018 | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | Yes | 2018 | 10 | 150 |
| 2 | Yes | 2020 | 0 | 200 |
| 2 | No | 2017 | 0 | 100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

My desired output should be like this:

| ID | Qualified | Year | Amount A | Amount B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No | 2020 | 0 | 150 |
| 1 | Partial | 2019 | 10 | 115 |
| 1 | Partial | 2018 | 10 | 250 |
| 2 | Yes | 2020 | 0 | 200 |
| 2 | No | 2017 | 0 | 100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

As you can see, Qualified column creates new merged values (Yes & No -> Partial, amount A + B ) from a condition: a year in an ID includes both Yes and No in Qualified column.

Don't know how to approach it. Anyone could provide any methodology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `agg()` and `groupby()` to perform this operation.

`agg()` allows you to use not only common aggregation functions (such as `sum`, `mean`, etc.) but also custom defined functions.

I would do as follows:

```
def agg_qualify(x):
    values = x.unique()
    if len(x)>1:
        return 'Partial'
    return values[0]

df.groupby(['ID', 'Year']).agg({
    'Qualified': lambda x: agg_qualify(x),
    'Amount A': 'sum',
    'Amount B': 'sum',
    }).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID   Year Qualified  Amount A  Amount B
0  1   2018    Partial        10     250.0
1  1   2019    Partial        10     115.0
2  1   2020        No          0     150.0
3  2   2020       Yes          0     200.0
```